# Box shadow not showing on the top or bottom

Tags: css

I am developing a site and I am running into an issue towards the bottom with the box-shadows on the three different sections. I want the border to show up around all three, but it only shows on the left and right.

Here is the HTML for that section:

```
<div class="three-cols-row">

<div class="three-cols-col three-cols">
<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://www.lytyx.com/subdomains/test/websites/mynaturerich.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/section01.jpg" alt="" /></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et. <a href="#">Read More</a></p>

</div>
<div class="three-cols-col three-cols">
<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://www.lytyx.com/subdomains/test/websites/mynaturerich.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/section02.jpg" alt="" /></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et. <a href="#">Read More</a></p>

</div>
<div class="three-cols-col three-cols">
<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://www.lytyx.com/subdomains/test/websites/mynaturerich.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/section03.jpg" alt="" /></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et. <a href="#">Read More</a></p>

</div>
</div>
<div class="clearboth"></div>
```

Here is the CSS for that section:

```
.three-cols-col{ margin:0 16px 0 16px; overflow:hidden; float:left; display:inline; }
.three-cols-row { margin:0 auto; width:960px; overflow:hidden; }
.three-cols-row .three-cols-row { margin:0 -16px 0 -16px; width:auto; display:inline-block; }
.three-cols { width:248px; padding: 15px; background: #fff; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #d4d4d4;-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #d4d4d4; box-shadow: 0 0 3px #d4d4d4; }
```

Comment: What, exactly, is the question you are asking? (Stack Overflow follows a question and answer format, and I'm not completely clear on the question part in this case.)

Comment: @aleshoug - Removing your site's link doesn't make it secret; people can still see it by looking at the edit history.  It's always better to put the relevant code right here in the question, and not use a live link anyway.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. Remove the `overflow: hidden` from all the parents node, because this is clipping your shadow. In your case, remove it from the following selectors: `.row`, `.column` and `.three-cols`.
2. You can just add some vertical margin to your: `.three-cols-col`. Instead of: `margin: 0 16px 0 16px;` you can just put: `margin: 16px 16px 16px 16px;`.

Both choices were tested on Google Chrome.

Comment: I chose the second option and it worked flawlessly. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 11):

The following statement has decided a similar problem:

```
position: relative;
```

Answer (score 2):

The parent element of your 3 boxes (`.three-cols-row`) doesn't have enough space to show the text-shadow which exists on the top and bottom of its children.  Try adding some padding:

```
.three-cols-row { padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; }
```

Example JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KatieK/zZhxr/1/

Answer (score -2):

```
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
```

Comment: How does position and z-index change the shadow? Please elaborate on your answer so it can help the OP.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.